# How can I add a class to a specific div only if another div has a specific style applied to it?

Tags: jquery

I have this setup:

```
<a id="slide-toggle" href="#"></a>

<div class="slide-container">
content here
</div>
```

It's a jQuery slide and div.slide-container slides down when I click on a#slide-toggle.

div.slide-container is originally set to display:none and the style changes to display:block through inline css when I click on a#slide-toggle.

Basically, I want to add a class to the 'a' tag when div.slide-container is in its down position (i.e. set to display:block).

How would I set something like this up?

-edit-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#slide-up').click(function() {
        $('.slide-container').slideUp('fast'); return false;});
        $('a#slide-toggle').click(function() {
        $('.slide-container').slideToggle('fast'); return false;
        });
});

$("a#slide-toggle").click(function() {
    if ($("div.slide-container").is("visible") {
        $("div.slide-container").slideUp();
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    } else {
        $("div.slide-container").slideDown();
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

-edit2-

Here is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#slide-up').click(function() {
        $('.slide-container').slideUp(); return false;});
    $('a#slide-toggle').click(function() {
        if ($('.slide-container').is(':visible')) {
            $('.slide-container').slideUp();
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        } 
        else {
            $('.slide-container').slideDown();
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

It works fine except when .slide-container is in the down position, there is a link in there (a#slide-up) which is just another way to close the container along w/ the toggle button. However, when I use that button to close the container, the toggle button remains in the active state. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$("a#slide-toggle").click(function() {
    if ($("div.slide-container").is("visible") {
      $("div.slide-container").slideUp();
      $(this).removeClass("class");
    } else {
        $("div.slide-container").slideDown();
        $(this).addClass("class");
    }
});
```

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6EK8/

```
    a:link              { color:red; text-decoration:underline; }
    a:visited           { color:red; text-decoration:underline; }
    a:hover             { color:green; text-decoration:underline; }
    a:active            { color:red; text-decoration:underline; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, Switz. I added that but I think it's conflicting with my previous script. Can you take a look? $(document).ready(function() { $('a#slide-up').click(function() { $('.slide-container').slideUp('fast'); return false;}); $('a#slide-toggle').click(function() { $('.slide-container').slideToggle('fast'); return false;});});
$("#slide-toggle").click(function() { if ($(".slide-container").is("visible") { $(".slide-container").slideUp(); $(this).removeClass("active"); } else { $(".slide-container").slideDown(); $(this).addClass("active"); } });

Comment: Put it in your first post, please.

Comment: Sorry, one more question: When the container is in the down position and I click on the slide up link, the toggle button remains in the active state. More info in the original post. Any ideas?

Comment: It shouldn't stay in the active state.  Maybe you mean that it turns purple meaning it's been clicked?  Use these:  (in post)